# How to filter a numpy array using another array's values?

Tags: python, arrays, filter, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays, e.g.:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and a filter array, e.g.:

```
f = [False, True, False, False, True]

len(a) == len(f)
```

How can I get a new numpy array with only the values in a where the same index in `f` is True? In my case: `[2, 5]`.

According to the accepted solution (with different values):

```
>>> a = numpy.array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> b = numpy.array([True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False])
>>> a[b]
array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```

Comment: it looks like b is a list not an array, b must be a boolean array. Try `b = np.asarray(b, 'bool')`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

NumPy supports [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

```
a[f]
```

This assumes that  `a` and `f` are NumPy arrays rather than Python lists (as in the question). You can convert with `f = np.array(f)`.

Comment: Make sure `b` is a numpy array. Updated in answer.

Comment: I changed it according to your solution and comment in the question ... now it works, thank you!

Comment: Recently started learning numpy, and i juest wanna say boolean indexing is pretty amazing

Answer (score 4):

If you don't already need numpy arrays, here's with a plain list:

```
import itertools
print itertools.compress(a, f)
```

For pre-2.7 versions of python, you must roll your own (see manual):

```
def compress(data, selectors):
    return (d for d, s in itertools.izip(data, selectors) if s)
```