# filtering a 3D numpy array according to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d

I have a 2D numpy array with the shape (3024, 4032).

I have a 3D numpy array with the shape (3024, 4032, 3).

2D numpy array is filled with 0s and 1s.

3D numpy array is filled with values between 0 and 255.

By looking at the 2D array values, I want to change the values in 3D array. If a value in 2D array is 0, I will change the all 3 pixel values in 3D array into 0 along the last axes. If a value in 2D array is 1, I won't change it.

I have checked this question, [How to filter a numpy array with another array's values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296658/how-to-filter-a-numpy-array-with-another-arrays-values), but it applies for 2 arrays which have same dimensions. In my case, dimensions are different.

How the filtering is applied in two arrays, with same size on 2 dimensions, but not size on the last dimension?

Comment: `I will change the pixel value in 3D array into 0` - All three values along the last axis?

Comment: `second_arr[first_arr==0] = 0`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer this to highlight one pecularity regarding "missing" dimensions. Lets' assume `a.shape==(5,4,3)` and `b.shape==(5,4)`

When **indexing**, existing dimensions are **left** aligned which is why @Divakar's solution `a[b == 0] = 0` works.

When **broadcasting**, existing dimensions are **right** aligned which is why @InvaderZim's `a*b` does not work. What you need to do is `a*b[..., None]` which inserts a broadcastable dimension at the right

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is very simple:

If a is a 3D array (a.shape == (5, 4, 3)) filled with values, and b is a 2D array (b.shape == (5, 4)) filled with 1 and 0, then reshape b and multiply them:

```
a = a * b.reshape(5, 4, 1)
```

Numpy will automatically expand the arrays as needed.

Comment: Did either you or OP who accepted this answer actually test it?

Comment: Thought I checked, but seems like I did not. Edited. Thanks :)