# How to multiply 3D array by 2D array, numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am standing in front of following problem: I have a stack of images - shape is `(x, y, N)`, and I want to multiply it fast by a 2D array - shape(x, y).

The only way I came up with is to interate through elements of the 2D array and multiply it :

```
 3D[id_x, id_y,:]=2D[id_x, id_y]*3D[id_x, id_y,:].
```

But for bigger arrays (and this is my case) it would not be time efficient. So here comes by question, do you how to do it without iteration?

Comment: I found the aswer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408448/filtering-a-3d-numpy-array-according-to-2d-numpy-array