# How to average over conditionally selected numpy array entries in a 4D array based on an index from a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to average over conditionally selected elements in a 4D numpy array, based on an index using a 3D array.

In other words, my 4D array **DATA** has these dimensions: [ntime,nz,ny,nx]

where as my 3D array **COND** which I use to conditionally sample is only a function of [ntime,ny,nx] (with the number of time slices, x and y points identical)

I want to do broadcasting, thus use something like `DATA[COND[None,...]]` But the problem is that the "missing" vertical dimension is not at the right, but in the middle between time and the x and y space.  I could loop over the vertical levels, but I think that would be slow.   Is there a way of somehow indexing DATA as

```
DATA[cond[times],:,COND[ys],COND[xs]]?
```

Setting up some dummy arrays:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
COND=np.random.randint(0,2,(2,3,3))  # 2 time levels, 3 X points and 3 y points
DATA=np.random.randint(0,100,(2,2,3,3)) # 2 time levels, 2 Z levels, and 3 x and y points
```

giving:

```
COND
array([[[1, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]])

DATA
array([[[[26, 58, 92],
         [69, 80, 73],
         [47, 50, 76]],

        [[37, 34, 38],
         [67, 11,  0],
         [75, 80,  3]]],
```

giving:

```
   [[[ 2, 19, 12],
     [65, 75, 81],
     [14, 71, 60]],

    [[46, 28, 81],
     [87, 13, 96],
     [12, 69, 95]]]])
```

I can find the argument using argwhere:

```
idx=np.argwhere(COND==1)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 2]])
```

Now I want to do something like

```
np.mean(DATA[idx[...,None,...]])
```

or

```
np.mean(DATA[idx[0],None,idx[1],idx[2])
```

which should give me an answer with 2 numbers corresponding to the mean DATA values at the times, x and y points when COND=1

This question is related to this:
[filtering a 3D numpy array according to 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408448/filtering-a-3d-numpy-array-according-to-2d-numpy-array)

but my klev index is in the middle and not the left or right, so I can't use the `[...,None]` solution

Comment: Can't you do something like: `DATA[np.expand_dims(COND,axis=1)]`? Or am I misunderstanding your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to get indices along each axis

IIUC, you have done most of the work, i.e. `idx`

```
>>> [*zip(*idx)]
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2)]

>>> t, y, x = zip(*idx)
>>> DATA[t, :, y, x]

array([[26, 37],
       [58, 34],
       [69, 67],
       [50, 80],
       [76,  3],
       [ 2, 46],
       [19, 28],
       [12, 81],
       [81, 96]])

>>> DATA[t, :, y, x].mean(0)
array([43.66666667, 52.44444444])
```

### Get indices using `np.where`

An easier way to get the [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> np.where(COND)
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64))
```

### Get indices using np.nonzero

Or, [`numpy.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), probably the most explicit:

```
>>> np.nonzero(COND)
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64))
```

### Use the condition array directly

Notably, a handy trick while dealing with `ndarray`s is `numpy.transpose`, as you would have seen in the linked post, in your question, while indexing, dimensions are left aligned, but your array in the current form is not suitable for that kind of indexing, so if your aggregation dimension was at the very right, and index dimensions were to the left, that would do the trick.

So, if your data could be reordered:

```
Instead of:
dim = (2, 2, 3, 3)
axis-> 0, 1, 2, 3

It were:
dim = (2, 3, 3, 2)
axis-> 0, 2, 3, 1
```

It would have worked.

### Reorder axes using `np.transpose`

You can use [`numpy.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) for that:

```
>>> np.transpose(DATA, axes=(0,2,3,1))[COND==1].mean(axis=0)
array([43.66666667, 52.44444444])
```

### Roll axes using `np.roll`

You could also `roll` your axis (==1) to the end (i.e. 4th dimension), using [`numpy.rollaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html):

```
>>> np.rollaxis(DATA, 1, 4)[COND==1].mean(0)
array([43.66666667, 52.44444444])
```

### Move axes using `np.transpose`

Or, you could `move` your axis from `source` dimension to `destination` dimension, i.e. move axis 1 to axis 3, using [`np.moveaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html):

```
>>> np.moveaxis(DATA, source=1, destination=3)[COND==1].mean(0)
array([43.66666667, 52.44444444])
```

Comment: my word, fantastic answer, that did the trick with zip, thank you so much!